# Copy all java files to specified folder

Tags: bash, cp

I have a input path `src` and output path `dest`. `src` can have multiple sub-directories, which can again have further sub-directories and so on. I want to copy all java files (and directories that contain them) from `src` to `dest` "as-is". That is, if `src` was:

```
src - 
   f1.java
   f4.txt
   dir_1 - 
      f2.java
      dir_2 -
         f3.java 
   dir_3 - 
      f5.txt
```

`dest` should look like:

```
dest - 
   f1.java
   dir_1 - 
      f2.java
      dir_2 -
         f3.java
```

I tried:

```
cp src/*.java dest
```

But it only copies `f1.java`, and nothing else. Can someone please help me out? (with solution/hints/links -- anything is good). I'm using ubuntu

Comment: You might also look into `rsync`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cd into `/path/to/src`, and run this:

```
find -type f -name '*.java' -exec cp --parents -t /path/to/dest {} +
```