# find + cp sparse directory tree

Tags: find, zsh, rsync

I have a directory tree which, among other files, has files which match certain patterns. For the sake of the discussion, let's assume these are files matching `*.foo`, or `*.bar`, or `baz*`. I want to backup inside my zsh-script **only files** matching these pattern to a new directory.

The seemingly obvious solution,

```
find fromdir \( -name '*.{foo,bar}' -o -name 'baz*' \) -exec cp {} todir \;
```

does not work, because the destination directory for, i.e., `fromdir/x/y/a.foo` does not exist.

I was thinking of using `rsync`, but I know only how to **exclude** certain files from being copied, not how to **restrict** copying.

I can solve the problem by writing a small auxiliary script, `mdcp1file`, like this:

```
#!/bin/zsh
set -u
mkdir -p $2/$1:h # Create destination directory if needed
cp $1 $2
```

and use it in my `find` command instead of `cp`. I wonder whether there is an easier way to solve this problem, either by beefing up the `-exec` of my `find`, or by using `rsync` in a clever way.

Comment: GNU cp has an option called `--parents`, have you tried that?

Comment: The man page explains this option as "use full source file name under DIRECTORY". It does not say that it would create the directories if necessary, but I found that it does. I find the man page confusing in this respect. If you write your comment as answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I've already posted an answer that uses `--parents` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62232917/10248678), I don't want to repeat myself. But if you post one I'll upvote it

Comment: I see that @kvantour has already posted  an answer which also uses `--parents` and gets rid of `find` too, and I accepted this. We could have also closed my question as duplicate, but I think it is pointless doing it at that stage.

Comment: With the zsh tag this wouldn't really be a duplicate of that question. You did the best, have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention that you make use of `zsh`, you could just do something like this:

```
cd /path/to/source/dir
cp --parents **/{*.{foo,bar},baz*}(.) /path/to/destination/dir
```

Here we make use of:

- **`cp --parents`:** [Bash: Copy named files recursively, preserving folder structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650164/bash-copy-named-files-recursively-preserving-folder-structure)
- **`**`:** for matching over multiple directories
- **BRACE EXPANSION:** A string of the form `foo{xx,yy,zz}bar` is expanded to the individual words `fooxxbar`, `fooyybar` and `foozzbar`.  Left-to-right order is preserved.  This construct may be nested.   Commas may be quoted in order to include them literally in a word.
- **Glob Qualifier `(.)`:** Patterns used for filename generation may end in a list of qualifiers enclosed in parentheses.  The qualifiers specify which filenames that otherwise match the given pattern will be inserted  in  the
  argument list. The `.` selects files only.

Comment: I like the idea of using globbing instead of `find`. The drawback is, if there are really many files, the arglist could get too long, but for my situation, I think I can do it that way. The crucial point for my question is the use of `--parents`.

Comment: @user1934428 you could also use `rsync` if you want, which fixes the issue with the argument list.

Comment: As I wrote, I tried, but did not know how to restrict the copying to only certain patterns. But maybe this should then go into a new question, if necessary, because, technically speaking, I do have a good solution now.

Comment: @user1934428 maybe this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111562/rsync-copy-over-only-certain-types-of-files-using-include-option